php8 how to properly define a errorHandler in a class?
In a class I use file_put_contents, which only gives a warning and not an exception to catch. The way to do it as I saw also in the docs is a callable function.
The examples I find are for non object oriented code or ancient. I am using php 8.2
My current code looks like this:

class CsvWriter
{
    public function errorHandler(int $severity, string $message, string $file, int $line): ?int
    {
        if (!(error_reporting() & $severity)) {
            return null;
        }
        $message = 'Error: ' . $message . ' in ' . $file . ' on line ' . $line;
        throw new \ErrorException($message, 0, E_ERROR);
    }

    public function addRow(array $row, string $filePath): bool|int
    {
        set_error_handler('App\Domain\FileReporting\Csv\CsvWriter::errorHandler');
        try {
            $data = implode(';', $row) . "\n";
            return file_put_contents($filePath, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        } catch (\ErrorException $e) {
            restore_error_handler();
            throw new FileException('Could not write to file ' . $filePath, 8789, $e);
        }
    }

with phpstan I now get the error:  Parameter #1 $callback of function set_error_handler expects (callable(int, string, string, int): bool)|null, 'App\\Domain…' given.
With phpunit I get: TypeError: set_error_handler(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback or null, class App\Domain\FileReporting\Csv\CsvWriter does not have a method "customErrorHandler"
So obviously I am doing it wrong. What is the correct way to set the temporary errorhandler?
This did also not work:
set_error_handler([$this,'errorHandler']);


Is the code you've shown definitely what you tried to run (i.e. a [mre])? Because one of the error messages you've shown mentions "customErrorHandler", which is never mentioned in the code shown.

Ah sorry.... yes I had it renamed. I just checked and tried to recreate my situation from 8 days ago.
Now it works.
